# Align text and image on the same line React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to align a text and an image that are wrapped in a text element in React Native.

This is what it currently looks like:
[image]

I'd like to have it aligned so it's even across.

This is the code I currently have:

```
<Text>
    <Text
        key={i}
        onPress={() => this.updateCurrentFilter(i)}
        style={{
            paddingLeft: 10,
            fontFamily: "Montserrat-Regular",
            fontSize: 12,
        }}
    >{v.filter_name}</Text>
    <Image
        source={require('../assets/outline_toggle_off_black_18dp.png')}
        style={{
            width: 25,
            height: 25,
            color: 'black',
            resizeMode: 'contain', 
        }}
    />
</Text>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work.  It's not clear why you're wrapping the outer level in a `Text` field instead of a `View`

```
<Text>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text style={{....}}}>foo</Text>
        <Image ... />
    </View>
</Text>
```

Comment: If you wrap them in a view, the image and the text do not stay on the same line; do you know you to get them on the same line?

Comment: @schoenbl there's no need to wrap the outer level in a `Text` field. It's usually best practice to use a `View` instead to wrap components. Mike's solution without the outer `Text` wrapping solves your problem. Here's a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@bmuthoga/rn-align-image-text?session_id=snack-session-UIvLd3qkq) that you can experiment with.

Comment: Generally the only time that I use a`Text` wrapper is to display different styles of text (e.g. a bolded word) on the same line.